# Tomcat cannot resolve '<%@ include file', possibly related to taglibs JasperException: File Not Found

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

In the jsp i have:

```
<%@ include file="/assets/includes/inc_standard_init.jsp" %>
```

In the browser I get:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /oprs.jsp(1,1) File "/assets/includes/inc_standard_init.jsp" not found
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407) ...
```

I've tried several versions of the path including ../assets, ../../assets, etc.  The weird thing is I do not have this problem in my primary development environment, only when I've tried to move to another computer.  I've compared the httpd.conf and server.xml files and I haven't been able to find any discrepancies between the environments.  Ultimately I think this is a configuration problem in either Apache 2.2.14 or Tomcat 5.5.27 configuration.

Additionally, when I go to http://localhost/assets/includes/inc_standard.jsp I get this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "/WEB-INF/tld/siteuser.tld" not found
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:116) ...
```

Obviously I shouldn't be able to access the contents of /WEB-INF directly.  I don't see how this is working in one environment but not the other.  Any Ideas?

/WEB-INF/lib:

```
acosog_utils.jar
activation.jar
ant-antlr-1.6.5.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
app.jar
asm-attrs.jar
asm.jar
autoform-ext.jar
autoform.jar
axis-ant.jar
axis-schema.jar
axis.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-deployer.jar
cglib-2.1.3.jar
classes12.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-collections-3.0.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-dbcp.jar
commons-dbutils-1.0.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-el.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-pool.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
domain.jar
ehcache-1.1.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
examples.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-entitymanager.jar
hibernate3.jar
ibatis-2.3.0.677.jar
jakarta-regexp-1.2.jar
jasper-compiler.jar
jasper-runtime.jar
jaxrpc.jar
jms.jar
jsp-api.jar
jstl.jar
jta.jar
junit.jar
kjdk.jar
log4j-1.2.11.jar
log4j.properties
mail.jar
mysql-connector-java-3.1.10-bin.jar
naming-common.jar
naming-factory.jar
naming-resources.jar
ojdbc14_g.jar
oracle_8.1.7.1_classes12.jar
portlet-api.jar
quartz-all-1.6.5.jar
RandoNode.jar
resolver.jar
saaj.jar
serializer.jar
servlet-api.jar
servlet.jar
siteuser.jar
spring-orm.jar
spring-web.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet.jar
spring-webmvc.jar
spring.jar
standard.jar
tools.jar
velocity-1.4.jar
velocity-dep-1.4.jar
wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
xerces.jar
xercesImpl.jar
xml-apis.jar
xml.jar
xmlparserv2.jar
```

apache-tomcat-5.5.27/common/lib:

```
commons-el.jar
jasper-compiler-jdt.jar
jasper-compiler.jar
jasper-runtime.jar
jsp-api.jar
naming-factory-dbcp.jar
naming-factory.jar
naming-resources.jar
servlet-api.jar
standard.jar
```

apache-tomcat-5.5.27/server/lib:

```
catalina-ant-jmx.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-cluster.jar
catalina-optional.jar
catalina-storeconfig.jar
catalina.jar
commons-modeler-2.0.1.jar
servlets-cgi.renametojar
servlets-default.jar
servlets-invoker.jar
servlets-ssi.renametojar
servlets-webdav.jar
standard.jar
tomcat-ajp.jar
tomcat-apr.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-http.jar
tomcat-jkstatus-ant.jar
tomcat-util.jar
```

Comment: Please post any tld related parts of your web.xml file, a listing of the files in /WEB-INF/lib, and a listing of the files in each of Tomcat5's 2 lib folders.

Comment: I added the lib directories.  I do not see anything in web.xml relating to tld.  I inherited this from another developer who is long gone and my taglib knowledge is limited.

Comment: /WEB-INF/tld/siteuser.tld - is this file there?
(you can access the WEB-INF folder from jsp scriptlets - they are processed server-side)

Comment: It is definitely there.  Whether it is being mapped correctly is another question.  Everything I've checked looks right, but I could be missing something.

Comment: While going through the tomcat logs I saw this when loading the page http://localhost/assets/includes/inc_standard_init.jsp:

WARN TP-Processor3 org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache - Internal Error: File /WEB-INF/web.xml not found

Answer (score 1):

First step is to remove **all** appserver specific JAR's out of the `WEB-INF/lib`. This includes the `servlet-api.jar` and `servlet.jar`. They would only coillide with the JAR's already available in the appserver's classpath and makes your webapp totally unportable.

You should never move/duplicate any appserver-specific JAR files outside their default location. You *may* add another webapp-specific JAR's to it so that they get shared among all webapps or any JAR's which are required by appserver's resource management (e.g. JDBC drivers for datasources), but nothing more than that.

Also ensure that the `JRE/lib` is kept default the same way. You should in no way add any 3rd party JAR's to it though.

Comment: Yeah, Tomcat reminds me of that whenever I restart it as well :).  Good general advice, but unfortunately it had no effect on this error.

Comment: Then you likely have a webapp-specific JAR file containing the TLD in your local Tomcat environment but which is missing in the other Tomcat environment. I should have added, if you don't have any "admin control" over the final appserver, then you shouldn't include any 3rd party JAR's in the appserver's classpath as well.

Comment: I've triple checked the dependencies and I'm sure that both environments have the same jars in the build path.  I also looked in all the jars and I wasn't able to find and TLD configuration.  I appreciate your help.  I've literally had this problem for years, and I have to do all development for this legacy system on the computer i had 2 computers ago, which is becoming more and more of a problem.

Comment: When I move anything up to the root directory of my web app it works great, they just don't work from subdirectories.

Comment: Interesting. Isn't there a servlet or filter in the request chain which is probably distracting the requests on a certain url-pattern?